# Pass Values From One Modal To Another

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, native-base

I am using these in one of my modals:

```
const [startingPoint, setStartingPoint] = useState('');

<Input
  placeholder="Start"
  onChangeText={inputText => setStartingPoint(inputText)}
  value={startingPoint}
/>
```

I want to pass the value, which was entered here to the next modal and automatically write it in another input field. I am trying to pass the value like this:

```
<AvailableTripsPage
  showAvailableTripsPage={showAvailableTripsPage}
  toggleShowPage={toggleAvailableTripsPage}
  startingPoint={startingPoint}
/>
```

This is from the second modal now where the value was passed.

```
const [newStartingPoint, setNewStartingPoint] = useState(startingPoint);

<Item fixedLabel>
   <Input 
      //onChangeText={text => setNewStartingPoint(text)}
      value={newStartingPoint}
   />
```

However, this doesn't work properly. Sometimes the value just doesn't show up. Or else, the value that I entered on the previous modal isn't updated. For example, if I wrote 'FirstPoint' in the beginning, and tried a few times with different values, it still shows 'FirstPoint' in the new modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` takes it argument as an *initial* value. This mean that, after you change it in the other Modal, it gets out of sync since `state` does not automatically updates on argument change.

You can do this adding an `useEffect` hook that will listen to `props.startingProps`, updating the state correctly, like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setNewStartingPoint(props.startingPoint);
}, [props.startingPoint]);
```